# I can't show my data in the Recyclerview inside the fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

Firstly It's my repo: https://github.com/Berkayszk/FiWoApp

In my application, I pull my data from Api and show it in Recyclerview with PagingData. I have created a similar section in the Details fragment and I am thinking of pulling my data by calling similar with the help of the Api in this part, but I see that my data is not loaded, no matter how hard I try, I cannot understand why this does not happen. I am trying to pull my data from a list in ViewModel to an adapter, but the data is not loaded.

It's my similarMovieAdapter

```
class SimilarMovieAdapter : PagingDataAdapter<Result,SimilarMovieAdapter.SimilarMovieViewHolder>(diffCallBack) {
class SimilarMovieViewHolder(val binding : PopularTvRowBinding): ViewHolder(binding.root)

companion object{
    val diffCallBack = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<com.example.fiwoapp.model.similarmovie.Result>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Result, newItem: Result): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id==newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Result, newItem: Result): Boolean {
            return oldItem==newItem
        }

    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SimilarMovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = getItem(position)
    holder.binding.apply {
        val imageLinkBackground = "${Constants.IMAGE_BASE_UR}${currentItem!!.poster_path}"
        imageViewPoster.load(imageLinkBackground){
            crossfade(1000)
            crossfade(true)
        }
        movieName.text = currentItem.title

    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SimilarMovieViewHolder {
    return SimilarMovieViewHolder(PopularTvRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))
}
```

This is my DetailsFragment, RecyclerView is in DetailsFragment. Here I get my data from viewmodel, but when I open my application, no data is visible.

```
 @AndroidEntryPoint
class MovieDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding : FragmentMovieDetailsBinding?=null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
private var movieId = 0
private val viewModel: MovieViewModel by viewModels()
private val args : MovieDetailsFragmentArgs by navArgs()
private lateinit var similarMovieAdapter : SimilarMovieAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    _binding = FragmentMovieDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)
    return binding.root


}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    movieId = args.movieId
    if (movieId>0){
        viewModel.loadDetailsMovie(movieId)
    }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    similarMovieRv()
    loadingSimilarData()
    showData()


}

private fun loadingSimilarData(){
    similarMovieAdapter = SimilarMovieAdapter()
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.movieSimilarList.collect{pagingData->
            similarMovieAdapter.submitData(pagingData)
        }
    }

}
private fun showDataSimilar(){

}

private fun showData(){
    binding.apply {
        viewModel.detailsMovie.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            val moviePosterUrlOrg = Constants.IMAGE_BASE_OR + it.backdrop_path
            val moviePosterUrl = Constants.IMAGE_BASE_UR+it.poster_path
            val studioPicture = Constants.IMAGE_BASE_UR+it.production_companies.get(0).logo_path
            imageDetailOriginal.load(moviePosterUrlOrg){
                crossfade(true)
                crossfade(1000)
                scale(Scale.FILL)
            }
            imageViewPoster.load(moviePosterUrl){
                crossfade(1000)
                crossfade(true)
                scale(Scale.FILL)
            }
            studioImageView.load(studioPicture){
                crossfade(true)
                crossfade(1000)
                scale(Scale.FILL)
            }
            tagLineText.text = it.tagline
            movieName.text = it.title
            releaseDate.text = it.release_date
            releaseDateInfo.text = "${"Revenue: "+ it.revenue.toString()}"
            studioName.text = it.production_companies.get(0).name
            subjectText.text = it.overview
            runTimeText.text = "${it.runtime.toString() +  "min"}"
            genreText.text = it.genres.get(0).name
            countryText.text = it.production_countries.get(0).name
            voteText.text = it.vote_average.toString()
            voteTextAll.text = it.vote_count.toString()

        }

    }
}

private fun similarMovieRv(){
    val similarMovieAdapter = SimilarMovieAdapter()
    binding.similarMovieRv.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
        adapter = similarMovieAdapter
        setHasFixedSize(true)

    }


}



override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    _binding=null
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your data is not loaded is because you are setting different instance of `adapter` to `recyclerview` and submitting list to different instance!

```
private fun loadingSimilarData(){
    //remove reassigning adapter here
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.movieSimilarList.collect{pagingData->
            similarMovieAdapter.submitData(pagingData)
        }
    }

}
private fun similarMovieRv(){
//remove val here and assign instance to class variable
    similarMovieAdapter = SimilarMovieAdapter()
    binding.similarMovieRv.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
        adapter = similarMovieAdapter
        setHasFixedSize(true)

    }
}
```